# Как запросить две соседние области?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

например два запроса:
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=37.620070,55.753630&spn=0.002,0.002&size=300,300&l=map

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?ll=37.622070,55.753630&spn=0.002,0.002&size=300,300&l=map

разница на 0.002 (на длину области):
37.620070
37.622070

я предполагаю, что получу две соседние области, но визуально это не так.
В чем моя ошибка?

с bbox аналогично:

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?bbox=37.631000,55.75000~37.632000,55.75100&size=400,400&l=map

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?bbox=37.632000,55.75000~37.633000,55.75100&size=400,400&l=map

я указываю во второй ссылке "начало" равное "концу" в первой и предполагаю увидеть, эту границу в одном случае слева, а в другом - справа. Но этого опять же не происходит.

И даже если мы например укажем те же точки в маркерах, они будут не в вершинах квадрата:

https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?bbox=37.631000,55.75000~37.632000,55.75100&size=400,400&l=map&pt=37.631000,55.75000,pm2rdl1~37.632000,55.75100,pm2rdl99

Comment: а какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить такими фрагментами?

Comment: В принципе я хотел сделать что-то вроде локального tile- сервера. Сейчас немного поизучал эту тему и мне показалось, что идеальным решением будет OpenStreetMaps или как ни странно это звучит - bing.

Comment: а у Yandex есть tile server? 100 процентов есть, но наверное его использование ограничено? Он как бы не афишируется, в тоже время с OpenStreetMaps на него натыкаешься в первую очередь.

Comment: Использовать static API вместо тайлов неоптимально. При этом использовать подложку Яндекс.Карт можно только посредством собственных API Яндекса, то есть условия запрещают выгрузить тайлы и отображать их в сторонней системе.